# Sub query to perform FX calculation on aggregate query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have a table of `transactions`. These have fields `id`, `trans_date`, `amount`, `currency`.

I have another table `fx_rates` with fields `id`, `fx_date`,`currency`, `rate_to_gbp`.

I wish to sum the GBP amount of transactions for a certain date. E.g.

```
SELECT format(transactions.trans_date, "mm-yyyy") as monthyear, sum(transactions.amount) as amount_sum
FROM transactions
GROUP BY format(transactions.trans_date, "mm-yyyy");
```

But some of my transactions are not in GBP. Is it possible to perform a currency conversion on those fields which have `transactions.currency <> "GBP"` by using a sub-query?

Something like:

```
sum(iif(transactions.currency = "GBP",
   transactions.amount,
   transactions.amount / (
     SELECT fx_rates.rate_to_gbp 
     WHERE fx_rates.currency = transactions.currency 
       AND transactions.trans_date = fx_rates.fx_date
   ))
```

???

Edit: Example data below...

Transactions:

```
id      account_id  trans_date  amount      currency
----------------------------------------------------
1797    GFSS35      28/01/2005  365000      USD 
1798    LA1F8       04/03/2005  100247.57                   
1799    IDFS12      31/03/2005  2396.89     GBP         
1800    DF088       06/04/2005  14000       EUR         
1801    BGD005      18/05/2005  450000
```

FX Rates:

```
id      fx_date     currency    rate_to_gbp
-------------------------------------------
3367    25/11/2018  USD         1.62
3368    25/11/2018  EUR         1.2
3369    25/11/2018  CHF         1.47
3412    11/12/2013  USD         1.64
3413    11/12/2013  EUR         1.2
3414    11/12/2013  CHF         1.46
```

Comment: The `fx_rates` table includes a `fx_date` field.  Does that mean there can be more than one row for each `currency` and you must reference the `fx_date` field to determine which of them applies to a specific `transactions.trans_date`?

Comment: In the FX rates table there shouldn't more than 1 row for each currency-date combo as there is a composite unique key that table. But I see what you mean, updated question

Comment: Please add brief samples of data for those two tables and show us your desired output from those data.

Comment: I can't tell you how off-putting it is to see 'mal-formatted' dates. :-(

Comment: I agree but this is just output from MS Access. I use ISO format it practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be doing a join.

```
SELECT format(transactions.trans_date, "mm-yyyy") as monthyear, 
  SUM(IIF(transactions.currency = "GBP" OR transactions.currency = "", 
    transactions.amount,
    transactions.amount/fx_rates.rate_to_gbp)) AS amount_sum
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN fx_rates 
ON fx_rates.currency = transactions.currency 
AND transactions.trans_date = fx_rates.fx_date
GROUP BY format(transactions.trans_date, "mm-yyyy");
```

I choose a LEFT JOIN since I wasn't sure if there would be a corresponding record in the fx_rates table when transactions.currency = "GBP". If there should, I would go with an INNER JOIN to avoid any instances where fx_rates.rate_to_gbp may be null.

Comment: What if, in my `fx_rates` table there are no entries for GBP (as rate_to_gbp = 1 for GBP)? Also, many `transactions` records have an empty string as their currency which is taken as that record being in GBP. Will this join method omit these records?

Comment: Yeah, the query should work as written then. Give it a go and let us know if there are errors.

Comment: Actually after looking it over again, I think there needs to be a second condition in the iif statement so that it will take transactions.amount even if currency is an empty string. You can similarly add more conditions for other strings that basically mean "GBP". Good Luck.